# Black boxes over HTML5 video tag, only in Safari 7 (OSX Mavericks)

Tags: html, video, safari, osx-mavericks

I have a gallery setup with multiple videos. These play perfectly on every browser I'm targeting (chrome/ie/firefox), except safari; but only on Safari 7/OSX Mavericks (other versions of safari are working fine): It displays black boxes over the videos, even when they are shown to be playing/loaded (a finished video will trigger its videoended() function, as intended, behind its black background).

The black boxes occur on the videos even when they are pulled outside the gallery, with nothing else affecting them. Sometimes not all videos get a black cover when refreshing; rarely none will.

This is a sample of one of the video tags:

```
<video id="video-1a" width="958px" onended="videoEnded()">
    <source src="/assets/video/product-1a.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="/assets/video/product-1a.webm" type="video/webm" /> 
</video>
```

Comment: try to add "autoplay" option: <video id="video-1a" autoplay width="640" height="480" onended="videoEnded()"> and/or even "controls" for your users.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I attempted autoplay, as well enabling the preload option. Those still give the same issue. However, enabling controls did fix the black box issue entirely. Unfortunately; for this setup/client I cannot use controls; the videos have to play by link clicks, and automatically when a previous video finishes.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem with Safari 7.x on Mac OS X 10.9.x "Mavericks — a black box would appear in Safari in place of an HTML5 video.

The previous comment of adding video controls does seem to address the problem, but has the potential downside of not being able to hide the controls in other browsers.

```
<video preload="auto" loop="loop" controls="controls">
    <source src="/path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="/path/to/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="/path/to/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

We can use the Shadow DOM to hide the controls in [browsers that support the property](http://caniuse.com/shadowdom) (Chrome 25+, Opera 15+), but have no choice in browsers that don't support it (Safari 3-7, IE 6-11).

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: none !important;
}
```

You can style the native video controls to some extent by addressing the Shadow DOM, using browser vendor specific pseudo element selectors, but these controls differ between browsers.

There is some interesting discussion on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/) about hiding native HTML5 video controls in full-screen mode, and cites [OzPlayer](http://www.accessibilityoz.com.au/products/ozplayer/) as an example.

**If full screen video is not what you're after or if having the controls visible is a deal-breaker, it would seem there isn't a solution** (unless you do some browser detection — though browser sniffing is bad!).

Alas, it seems like this behavior may be a bug in Safari (7.0) on Mavericks (10.9) since it didn't exist on Mountain Lion (10.8).

Comment: Good job on the investigation. I reported this problem to Apple and referenced this question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Voted @rjb up on diagnosing the issue.
Another way to solve it is to use setTimeout and remove the controls after a short period (40 ms):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#targetvid').removeAttr('controls');
}, 40);
```

I found that I could also not use controls and instead just alter the display property after 40 ms:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#targetvid').css('display','block');
}, 40);
```

If you want to restore it to its original display property (ours was inline-block), you could do that after 80 ms:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#targetvid').css('display','block');
}, 40);
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#targetvid').css('display','inline-block');
}, 80);
```

It's not a pretty JS hack but it works for this Safari bug.